# Handle button click event in Xamarin

Tags: android, xamarin

I'm new in Xamarin and not so good at English for reading the related mannuels.
Could someone express me how do I handle this button's click event method in code behind for Xamarin?

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage =new ContentPage{
            Content= new Button{Text="Click me",BackgroundColor=Color.Black,HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,TextColor=Color.White}
    };
}
```

Comment: Check this out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36855674/visual-studio-xamarin-onclicklistener/36855872?noredirect=1#comment61281011_36855872

Comment: Please consider using this link for these very basic questions. It will take you through the basics of developing Xamarin with Forms https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/getting-started/introduction-to-xamarin-forms/

Comment: Your previous question was "How to add a button in Xamarin.Forms?".  Please do a little research before posting your questions.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App ()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage =new LaunchPage();
    }
}
public class LaunchPage:ContentPage
{
    public LaunchPage ()
    {
        var button=new Button{Text="Hello World",BackgroundColor=Color.Black,HorizontalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,VerticalOptions=LayoutOptions.Center,TextColor=Color.White};
        button.Clicked += ButtonClicked;
        Content = button;
    }
    void ButtonClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        DisplayAlert ("Button Clicked", "This Button has been clicked", "OK");
    }
}
```